# Python : For loop to read a text file is not executing properly for all text file records

Tags: python

i am having a doubt regarding the below code.

i am trying to take a txt file as an input which will have the data as below

```
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccc
```

and pass it to the searchForJob function to perform a search in different file but my for loop of input file is not executing properly it is not taking all the three lines of input file. It is only picking either the second line ( bbbbbbbb ) or third line ( ccccccccc ). Can someone pls help me on this. I am new to python language.

```
def searchForJob(job):
    with open('some location/Jls.txt',"U") as lines:
        for line in lines:
            if line.find(job)!=-1:
                print(job + ' : Found')
                break;

    return




jobNames = open('some location/JNames.txt')
try:
    for job in jobNames:
        print(job)
        searchForJob(job)
finally:
    jobNames.close()
```

Comment: What is the "U" supposed to do in the second argument of `open` in `searchForJob`? i would expect that to be a mode.

Comment: 'U' is perhaps to see new lines in the txt file

Comment: you want to search aaaaa bbbbbb cccc in multi text files?

Comment: yes milti text file means it will be a raw text file with 'n' number of lines

Comment: @MykWillis "U" is the universal newline mode (no more available in Python 3) to convert non-Linux line-endings

Comment: @MykWillis : ok so removal of 'U' will not make any change in the code u mean to say ?

Comment: Does `print(job)` show all lines?

Comment: @MichaelButscher : yes if i comment the searchForJob function call then it prints in sequence all three ( aaaaaa, bbbbbb , cccccc ) but if i simply run the program without commenting then it prints 'aaaaa' then 'bbbbbb' then 'bbbbbb' : Found then 'ccccc' : Found even though the 'aaaa' is present inside the text input file

Comment: Try [`if job in line`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations).  Also print `job` and `line` at the top of the loop (`ctrl-c` will stop it if it is a long file) - examine what prints, see if there is a clue. Uppercase/lowercase/mixed-case??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading a file, use the `r` mode.

Each line has a trailing `\n`, so you need to `strip()` them. Use `repr(...)` function so that you can see the trailing white spaces.

Use Python language features such as the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), the [`in` keyword](http://www.jworks.nl/2013/11/07/python-goodness-the-in-keyword/)

Follow the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide.

```
def search_for_job(job):
    with open('j.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if job in line:
                print(repr(job) + ' : Found in ' + repr(line))
                break


with open('n.txt', 'r') as job_names:
    for job in job_names:
        job = job.strip()
        print('Searching for job ' + repr(job))
        search_for_job(job)
```

j.txt

```
job 1, name 2...
job 2, name 1...
job 3, nothing
```

n.txt

```
name 1
name 2
name 3
```

Sample output:

```
$ python3 read.py
Searching for job 'name 1'
'name 1' : Found in 'job 2, name 1...\n'
Searching for job 'name 2'
'name 2' : Found in 'job 1, name 2...\n'
Searching for job 'name 3'
```

Comment: i am still getting the same output. same prob occurring again :(

Comment: @AmritpalsinghThethi Did you check for the ending `\n` new line characters?